# Divide RGB image by grayscale elementwise in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose we have two arrays of shape (480, 640, 3) and (480, 640), say RGB and grayscale image. How you divide elementwise first array by the second? So far I use the following code, but is there a better snippet for it?

```
arr1[:, :, 0] /= arr2
arr1[:, :, 1] /= arr2
arr1[:, :, 2] /= arr2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add another axis to `arr2` so that it will [broadcast](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/basics.broadcasting.html#broadcasting).

```
>>> a = np.ones((2,2,3))
>>> b = np.ones((2,2)) * 2
>>> a
array([[[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.]],

       [[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.]]])
>>> b
array([[ 2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.]])
>>> a = a / b[:, :, np.newaxis]
>>> a
array([[[ 0.5,  0.5,  0.5],
        [ 0.5,  0.5,  0.5]],

       [[ 0.5,  0.5,  0.5],
        [ 0.5,  0.5,  0.5]]])
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... you could perhaps duplicate your grayscale array and just do one division?

```
arr1 /= arr2.repeat(3).reshape(np.shape(arr1))
```

Comment: Yep, it works. Couple of more snippets in that fashion ```arr1 / cv2.cvtColor(arr2, cv2.cv.CV_GRAY2BGR)``` and ```arr1 / np.dstack((arr2, arr2, arr2))```. Drawback is that arr1 should have last dimension of 3, case when arr1 is grayscale need to handle separately.

Comment: I think `arr1 / np.dstack([arr2]*3)` should also work

Answer (score 1):

Here's a snippet that might work:

```
result = np.dstack([x/np.reshape(arr2,(480,640,1)) for x in np.dsplit(arr1,3)])
```

Split your RGB array into 3 2D arrays, divide each by the greyscale array and recombine.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`np.divide`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.divide.html) after adding a singleton dimension to `arr2` to do *in-situ* edit of `arr1` elements as that's what your code seems to be doing. The advantage would be that this would be memory efficient. Here's the implementation -

```
np.divide(arr1,arr2[:,:,None],arr1)
```

---

You could also use [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html)'s broadcasting capabilities -

```
arr1 = np.einsum('ijk,ij->ijk',arr1,1/arr2)
```